# Group By records from csv file

Tags: c#, linq

I'm loading CSV file

[image]

Into:

```
 public class ReleaseVersion
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReleaseNote> ReleaseNotes { get; set; }

}

public class ReleaseNote
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Progress { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

How can i group all records by version and return list of **ReleaseVersion**?

Here is what i did, however i did't know how to group by first column which is the version column in the file.

```
var records = csvLinesData.Select(data => new ReleaseVersion
        {

            Version = data[0],
            ReleaseDate = TryParse(data[1]),
            // add list of ReleaseNote ??
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `GroupBy` on  the first item:

```
  DateTime date;

  var records = csvLinesData
    .GroupBy(line => line[0]) // line[0] is version we want to group by on
    .Select(chunk => new ReleaseVersion() {
       Version = chunk.Key,
       ReleaseDate = DateTime.TryParse(chunk.First()[1], out date) 
          ? (DateTime?) date 
          : null,
       ReleaseNotes = chunk
         .Select(item => new ReleaseNote() {
            Description = item[2],
            Progress = item[3],
            Status = item[4], }) 
         .ToArray(), })
    .ToList();
```